# Can I end up with a pointer to an unintended location by passing a pointer to a stack variable to a function in C++?

Tags: c++, object, heap-memory, stack-memory

I know compiler optimization can sometimes result in the stack frames volatility. So my question is if it is always safe to create a stack pointer in c++ and pass it to another function and expect it to point to the same object in the callee. Is it possible to end up pointing to an unintended location because of compiler optimization.

For example is this always safe with any compiler?

```
int main(){
   std::ofstream f("somefile");
   foo(&f);
   return 0;
}
```

or should I use heap for consistent results.

```
int main(){
   std::ofstream *f=new std::ofstream("somefile");  
   foo(f);
   close(*f);
   delete f;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your first example wouldn't even compile.

Comment: An optimization should not transform correct code into incorrect code (a compiler that produces an incorrect program from correct code is buggy). Your concern should perhaps be: 'is my code correct such that compiler optimizations will produce a correct result'.

Comment: @LucDanton Have you not heard of programmers complaining that their code worked on a system for years and then it suddenly stopped working either because of new system/compiler or that compiler could act differently?

Comment: @MoZo: That can only happen when either the compiler or the code contains a bug. If the code is incorrect, it is incorrect regardless of whether this only shows up when an optimising compiler is used, and if the code is correct, it is a bug in the compiler if it does not produce a correct result after optimisation. Luc Danton is pointing out that "because of compiler optimization" is not a valid reason for code to go from correct to incorrect.

Comment: Note that I said 'correct code', not 'code that works'. This should also be one of your concerns! (All told I'm not saying that there are no buggy compilers or tools; but you can't code your way out of those.)

Comment: If you were drawing the blueprint for a boat, you shouldn't ask "should I make it a double-hull in case the builders make a mistake?". If the builders are incompetent enough to leave a hole in a hull, there's no telling how many holes they leave in a double-hull.

Answer (score 5):

A [dangling pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer) is created when a pointer exists that points to an object who's lifetime has ended:

```
std::string* s;
{
    std::string s1("hello");
    s = &s1;
}
// 's' now a dangling pointer because 's1' has been destructed.
```

This situtation does not exist in either of the posted code snippets, so both are safe. (though the first is preferable as it avoid unnecessary dynamic memory allocation).

Comment: Look again, the first example won't compile because they are trying to initialize an `ofstream` pointer with a string pointer.

Comment: Except that the first one wouldn't even compile.

Comment: My understanding from programming in c was that it is not safe to pass a pointer to a stack location to another function as the compiler could optimize the code and therefore, your pointer could end up pointing to an unintended location. That is what I mean by dangling pointer.

Comment: @juanchopanza, yes I know. I was conentrating more on the dangling pointer issues that compilation errors.

Comment: @MoZo, it is safe to pass a pointer as long as they object to which pointer refers remains during use of the pointer.

Comment: are you sure? I have most definitely heard of bugs in c where the cause was that the pointer was not pointing to the intended location in the callee.

Comment: @MoZo Absolutely certain. In fact, there's no practical difference between your two bits of code. In both, the pointer passed to `foo` points at a valid object.

Answer (score 2):

The lifetime of an object defined within a block extends to the end of the block, on matter which functions are called between the object definition and the end of the block. Thus your first example has no problems.

You are probably confused by the opposite approach: it is *not* safe to return a pointer to an object local to a function:

```
std::ofstream * foo() {
  std::ofstream f("somefile");
  return &f;
}

int main() {
  std::ofstream * f = foo();
  // At this point there's no guarantee that f points to a valid object
}
```

Comment: I would like to rephrase it to "Thus your first example has no problems, *if `foo` has no side-effects, such as storing the pointer value*".

Comment: You're right, however if it does it's just a more convoluted instance of my example above. In other words `foo()` should not store the pointer value in an object whose lifetime extends that of `foo()` itself.